# Why can't I create a Windows Virtual Machine on Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, virtualbox, windows-10, virtualization

Hello Ubuntu community.

I tried to create a Windows 8 virtual box in Ubuntu 20.04, to use Power BI, but I didn't get. I have an Acer Aspire 5, Intel Core i5, 4G RAM, 1000 GB HDD.

I installed Gnome Box, downloaded the Windows 8 ISO, but when tried to create the virtual box with Gnome box chosen the windows ISO and Gnome box did anything.

After that I tried with VirtualBox, when I have chosen the Windows ISO and the same that gnome anything did VirtualBox.

And next I tried with QEMU/KVM, when I have chosen Windows 8 ISO it tried to work, but the computer become too slow, and after that QEMU/KVM gives error.

Next I tried with Windows 10 ISO, but the same.

A message appeared when I tried to install virtualbox "your system has UEFI secure boot enabled", and didn't allow to give "ok". I went to the BIOS and change the enabled of EFI, by disabled, and vice verse, but doesn't work. I don't get have a Windows 8 Virtual Machines on Ubuntu 20.4.

In the last I upgrade to Ubuntu 22.4 but the same problem, I can't get a Virtual Machine.

Please give me option of solutions. I need to work with Power BI and SQL Server, Excel.
Please help me.

Update: I didn't get solutions to install a windows virtual box on my laptop. But I installed Power BI. I put the two operating system on my laptop (Dual Boot).

Comment: 4GB of RAM are very tight to run an Ubuntu host but doable (with many caveats). I've did years ago for a Windows 10 VM assigning only 1,5GB of RAM (you can't assign more than half of the total RAM and even close to it is dangerous territory). Even worse when you only have and integrated GPU (in the i5) which necessarily takes some RAM (discrete GPUs have their own VRAM so they don't have to "steal" it from the main RAM). Then, of course, you must have VT-x/VT-d enabled in UEFI. I wonder if there was the error message in Virtualbox? Other tools might not react the same way and simply don't work

Comment: Please check all that has been commented before and then update, [edit] your question accordingly and don't forget to post a link to any documentation, tutorial, etc. you might be follwing.

Comment: *Correction: *4GB of RAM are very tight to run an Ubuntu host **and a Win8/10 VM** but doable (with many caveats)

Comment: Complete, accurate error messages are also very helpful to understand what is occurring.